# Determine hierarchical relationship, but in reverse

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider the following table in Oracle

```
sortOrder           thisID              levelNo
------------------- ------------------- ---------------------
1                   A                   0
2                   B                   1
3                   C                   1
4                   D                   2
5                   E                   3
6                   F                   3
7                   G                   1
8                   H                   0
9                   I                   1
```

Which could be seen visually as

```
A
 B
 C
  D
   E
   F
 G
H
 I
```

How could I determine the child parent relationship, to output the following below? The relationship is based on the sortOrder and levelNo.

```
thisID              parentID
------------------- ---------------------
A                   A
B                   A
C                   A
D                   C
E                   D
F                   D
G                   A
H                   H
I                   H
```

I am familiar with using queries to determine the level based on a hierarchical parent-child relationship, but haven't figured out a way to do it in reverse.

Comment: Is child = parent + 1 ? Very unclear.. Please add more details.. How come G->A !!

Comment: The first table seems to show the level within the hierarchy; however, it does not show which child is related to which parent. Can you explain us the logic behind table 1?

Comment: Also the relationship seems to depend on the position in the table; however, there is no natural row number given in a table. Oracle could decide to return rows in any order, if a query contains no ORDER BY clause.

Comment: I edited the post to answer the previous questions and make it clearer.

Comment: Oh man.. This sounds very interesting!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
SELECT
  T.thisID
  , CASE T.levelNo 
    WHEN 0 
         THEN T.thisID
    ELSE (
           SELECT thisID FROM Table1
           WHERE sortOrder = (
                               SELECT MAX(sortOrder) FROM Table1 
                               WHERE (levelNo = T.levelNo -  1) 
                                 AND sortOrder < T.sortOrder
                             )
         )
  END parent
FROM Table1 T
ORDER BY sortOrder;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/39241).

Please comment if and as further detail / adjustment is required.

Comment: This works great, but hangs on very large recordsets. Do you have any ideas on how to optimize it?

Comment: What is "very large" in this case? Indices on "levelNo" and "sortOrder" are in place? Is the tree rather high (high values for "levelNo") or wide? Is that a one time only job? Which version of Oracle?

Comment: What kind of processing follows the retrieval?

Comment: 500,000+ records. 80,000 records took 90 minutes to insert into a new table. The other one with more than 500,000 records ran for 6 hours before I stopped it. Indices are in place. The max value for levelNo is 5. Oracle 11g. This is a one time job.

Comment: So, taking the easy road "Cut the 500,000+ records into batches of something between 50,000 and 80,000 along `… FROM Table1 T WHERE t.thisID BETWEEN 1 AND 50000 …`" - would that be acceptable to you?

Comment: Overall output should essentially be identical: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/39272/0)